# Remapping single Glyphs in small caps (Linux Libertine)

Tags: fonts, mapping

I am trying to remap the default style of the German sharp s (Eszett) to another Linux libertine.  This works when adding

```
 U+00DF <> U+E04C
```

to tex-text.map (and compiling this map file).  The problem is this has the side-effect that the small cap sharp s is also replaced by U+E04C while it should remain U+E092 (small majuscule German sharp s in Linux Libertine's private area).

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

Rainer

Comment: You should load the small caps font separately, with a different map file. This is an example showing it's a bad idea to modify a standard file.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify the standard `tex-text.map`. Rather, add the change to a new file (I named it `change-ss.map`) and run `teckit_compile` on it.

Then you can load it for the main font and pass different options for the small caps font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
  Mapping=change-ss,
  SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Mapping=tex-text,Letters=SmallCaps},
]

\begin{document}

This is a ß

\textsc{This is a ß}

\end{document}
```

[image]